# How to save the value in JTextArea into JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I have a `JTable` with four columns, in the fourth column I placed the `JTextarea`.. After entering the value in text area, I will reload the table , at that time value inside text area is not get saved and text area is empty.

How to solve my problem, suggestions please?

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) and consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get access through getter. Like

```
public JTextArea getTextArea()
{
    return jTextAreaField;
}
```

and then

```
getTextArea().append("ur text");
```

Comment: From within in a `JTable`, I truly hope not.  The value of the cell should be stored within the model and should have no concept of the UI or how it is intended to be rendered.  The `TableCellRederer` (and/or `TableCellEditor`) should then make decisions about how best to renderer the cell value

Comment: Thank You Bro.. I have another doubt , I have two JTables with four columns each, I placed the JTextarea in the Fourth column of both tabe, I entered the value in the Jtextarea of first table , then I clicked the second table and entered in value jtextarea.. After that I reload both the tables, but the jtextarea column is empty.. Please give me some suggestions

Comment: @VishwaDany DON'T add components to the table, you MUST use `TableCellRenderer`s to render the cell value and `TableCellEditor`s to edit the values, read the linked tutorials in the comments!